# lambda use in onclick listener

Tags: android, lambda, warnings

I have used lambda in my application for calling functions and click listeners so google play store is throwing warnings of `nonsdkvoilation` and `landroid` use of lambda how i can resolve it i have also change jre and jdk to new one i am using java 8 in android studio. my application is submitted on playstore and now i have to upload build after resolve of this issue.

```
button->{}
```

So google play store is throwing warnings of `nonsdkvoilation` and `landroid` use of lambda.

How I can resolve it? I have also change jre and jdk to new one I am using java 8 in android studio.

Comment: Have you tried running lint? Was the errors/warnings not reported then?

Comment: after upload of application play store showing warning on dashboard for its lambda use nonsdkvoilation